# Linking with 2 libraries

Tags: makefile, linker, fortran, shared-libraries, intel

I'm trying to link a program with 2 libraries this way:

```
LNOPT = -Wl,-rpath,$(MKLROOT)/lib/intel64  -Wl,-rpath,/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2019.0.117/linux/compiler/lib/intel64_lin
```

However I either get one of these errors:

```
./dftb+: error while loading shared libraries: libmkl_gf_lp64.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

./dftb+: error while loading shared libraries: libiomp5.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Depending on which -rpath I put first. How can I address this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Is putting both paths (separated by `:`) in the environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` at runtime an option? (This way, the hard-coded rpath doesn't have to work.)
Example:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$(MKLROOT)/lib/intel64:/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2019.0.117/linux/compiler/lib/intel64_lin ./dftb+
```

Or put `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$(MKLROOT)/lib/intel64:/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2019.0.117/linux/compiler/lib/intel64_lin` in some profile `rc` file so that the library path is always set.

In either case, if there are already other paths which are needed in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` add the above to it via `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$(MKLROOT)/lib/intel64:/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2019.0.117/linux/compiler/lib/intel64_lin:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` instead of simply overriding `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` completely.

What could/should also work is `source`ing the environment variable setup `.sh` files shipped with both the Intel compilers and the MKL, which, among other variables such as MKLROOT, should setup LD_LIBRARY_PATH pointing to both `libiomp5.so` and also the dynamic MKL link libraries.